# Ajax datatype Response changes to string although its mentioned as Json

Tags: c#, jquery, http, iis

I am working on an application where we pull some data from DB to show on the form.
Below was the ajax request.

```
  $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                url: versionURL,
                dataType: "json",                
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { isIPA: true },
                success: function (data) {
                    var labelValue = "";
                    if (data != null && data != undefined && data.Result != "") {
                        labelValue = "v" + data.Result;
                    }
                    $('#lblVersionNumber').text(labelValue);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
            });
```

Initially, the response returned from the server will be Json type. After a few hours or a day, the response changes to String without any deployments.
When I recycle the app pools it again resets the response back to Json.
The same code works on other farm machines for other clients. ANything specific that I can look for? Thanks in advance.

JSON Response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Success": true,
    "ErrorMessages": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$values": []
    },
    "Result": "2.5.108.245"
}
```

String Response:

```
{
"success": "true",
"ErrorMessages":[],
"result": "2.5.108.245"
}
```

Note: We recently updated our farm machines to support Http 2

Comment: According to your description and reponse example, I couldn't find out the reason directly. In my opinion the two kinds of response are all json type. I suggest you could post some part of server-side code to help us understand  your question clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to get to the root cause. We have some code in Basecontroller thats overriding the server config jsonformat.